# Can't Generate Certificate Exception When Generating Key Pair In API 21

Tags: android, security, android-5.0-lollipop, android-keystore

I've been trying to solve this exception that only happens in Android Lollipop (API 21). I tried to look for other solutions but the only one related is [Generate KeyPair with KeyPairGeneratorSpec on API < 23](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43387810/generate-keypair-with-keypairgeneratorspec-on-api-23) and the suggested solution didn't work.

Am I missing anything? Thanks!

Here's my code that's throwing at the last line:

```
Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance();
                    Calendar end = Calendar.getInstance();
                    end.add(Calendar.YEAR, 30);
                    KeyPairGeneratorSpec spec = new KeyPairGeneratorSpec.Builder(appContext)
                            .setAlias(getSecureSettingsKeyAlias())
                            .setSubject(new X500Principal("CN=" + getSecureSettingsKeyAlias()))
                            .setSerialNumber(BigInteger.TEN)
                            .setStartDate(start.getTime())
                            .setEndDate(end.getTime())
                            .build();
                    KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_RSA, AndroidKeyStore);
                    kpg.initialize(spec);
                    kpg.generateKeyPair();
```

Here's the exception that's happening:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't generate certificate
   at android.security.AndroidKeyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair(AndroidKeyPairGenerator.java:136)
   at java.security.KeyPairGenerator$KeyPairGeneratorImpl.generateKeyPair(KeyPairGenerator.java:276)
   at com.sampleid.sampleid_sdk.common.FileSettingsStorage.getKeystore(FileSettingsStorage.java:302)
   at com.sampleid.sampleid_sdk.common.FileSettingsStorage.writeSecureSettings(FileSettingsStorage.java:185) 
   at com.sampleid.sampleid_sdk.common.SettingsImpl.saveSecureSettings(SettingsImpl.java:473) 
   at com.sampleid.sampleid_sdk.common.SettingsImpl.saveSettings(SettingsImpl.java:321) 
   at com.sampleid.sampleid_sdk.sampleIDService.saveSettingsToStorage(sampleIDService.java:102) 
   at com.sampleid.sampleid_sdk.sampleIDService.saveSettings(sampleIDService.java:91) 
   at com.sampleid.sampleid.features.shared.BaseActivity.onStop(BaseActivity.java:182) 
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStop(Instrumentation.java:1261) 
   at android.app.Activity.performStop(Activity.java:6089) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:3341) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:3390) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:144) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1307) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694) 
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: private exponent cannot be extracted
   at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLRSAPrivateKey.getPrivateExponent(OpenSSLRSAPrivateKey.java:161)
   at org.spongycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.rsa.RSAUtil.generatePrivateKeyParameter(RSAUtil.java:63)
   at org.spongycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.rsa.DigestSignatureSpi.engineInitSign(DigestSignatureSpi.java:95)
   at java.security.Signature$SignatureImpl.engineInitSign(Signature.java:679)
   at java.security.Signature.initSign(Signature.java:330)
   at com.android.org.bouncycastle.x509.X509Util.calculateSignature(X509Util.java:243)
   at com.android.org.bouncycastle.x509.X509V3CertificateGenerator.generate(X509V3CertificateGenerator.java:434)
   at com.android.org.bouncycastle.x509.X509V3CertificateGenerator.generate(X509V3CertificateGenerator.java:412)
   at android.security.AndroidKeyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair(AndroidKeyPairGenerator.java:133)
   at java.security.KeyPairGenerator$KeyPairGeneratorImpl.generateKeyPair(KeyPairGenerator.java:276) 
   at com.sampleid.sampleid_sdk.common.FileSettingsStorage.getKeystore(FileSettingsStorage.java:302) 
   at com.sampleid.sampleid_sdk.common.FileSettingsStorage.writeSecureSettings(FileSettingsStorage.java:185) 
   at com.sampleid.sampleid_sdk.common.SettingsImpl.saveSecureSettings(SettingsImpl.java:473) 
   at com.sampleid.sampleid_sdk.common.SettingsImpl.saveSettings(SettingsImpl.java:321) 
   at com.sampleid.sampleid_sdk.sampleIDService.saveSettingsToStorage(sampleIDService.java:102) 
   at com.sampleid.sampleid_sdk.sampleIDService.saveSettings(sampleIDService.java:91) 
   at com.sampleid.sampleid.features.shared.BaseActivity.onStop(BaseActivity.java:182) 
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStop(Instrumentation.java:1261) 
   at android.app.Activity.performStop(Activity.java:6089) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:3341) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:3390) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:144) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1307) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about your attempt at the solution that you pointed to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was finally able to solve this. The issue is with the following:

```
KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_RSA, AndroidKeyStore);
```

`KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_RSA` is only available starting API 23, so it fails in APIs before that. Replace it with "RSA"

Also, if you're using SpongyCastle, it should be added using the following approach:

```
static {
        // as per https://github.com/rtyley/spongycastle/issues/27
        Security.addProvider(new org.spongycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());
    }
```